# Why is process.env._ undefined on some versions of nodejs in some circumstances?

Tags: node.js, docker

In nodejs, running a nodejs script as the entrypoint in a docker container, I found `process.env._` undefined and my code threw an exception.  If use bash as the entry point and run the same program, the field is defined.

This was on node v4.3.2.  It worked fine on node 0.10.x as an entrypoint.

The OS for both cases is Ubuntu Wily.

Is this field not guaranteed to be defined?  I couldn't find a specification on this.

The Real Question:  Do I have to guard all code that uses process.env fields?

Comment: I had the same issue. If you are looking for node executable path, inside the node process, it looks like `process.execPath` would do it. https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_execpath

Answer (score 0):

process.env._ is referencing the environment variable named _

If the environment variable is NOT set then it will be undefined.

If you can guarantee the environment variable is set then no guard is required.

If you cannot guarantee it is set then you could provide a default ...

```
var myvar = process.env._ || "defaultValue";
```

Comment: I should have added that `process.env._` is the fully qualified path name of the process in question.  Basically, there's no way to find out what the process name is under some circumstances....